# How do I configure Debian to use available physical memory to speed up Samba connections?

Tags: debian, samba, memory

I want to maximize the speed of the connections by using more of the available RAM that we have in our server (there's 4GB worth). What files would I need to edit, what directives would I need to add, etc.? How difficult would it be to implement something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux will automatically manage and use the available memory for caches that speed up Samba (or any other I/O operation really). What you can do is tune swappiness and how the kernel will deal with those caches and buffers. You can read [this](http://unixfoo.blogspot.com.br/2007/11/linux-performance-tuning.html) for understanding/tuning swappiness and [this](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap29sec287.html) about buffer invalidation and times.

A good reference for other performance tunings on samba is the O'Reilly book, there's a part of it online [here](http://oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/appb_02.html)

Comment: In addition, you can improve performance if you use appropriate block sizes, aligned blocks and read-ahead settings for the block devices - disk, raid, lvm.